# В чем разница между URL Rewriting, encodeURL, encodeRedirectUrl

Tags: java, cookie, сессия

URL Rewriting как я понял нужен для поддержания сессии в случае если в браузере отключены куки (Поправьте пожалуйста, если я не прав).

И вот дальше не понятно то ли он в URL id сессии записывает при этом есть еще encodeRedirectUrl и encodeURL которые вроде то же самое делают...

Помогите разобраться в этих трех подходах:

1. URL Rewriting
2. encodeURL
3. encodeRedirectUrl

Что в них общего и в чем разница между проблемами которые они решают?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**URL Rewriting** - общее название метода для работы с url в контексте сессии.

**encodeURL()** - функция, реализующая логику обработки url такого вида:

- cookies включены - возвращаем url без изменений
- cookies отключены/выключенно отслеживание - возвращаем url с
  идентификаторов сессии

**encodeRedirectURL** - практически тоже самое, но используется для перенаправления в sendRedirect. Отличие в том, что дополнительно происходит проверка перехода в другой контекст или другой ресурс.